# How to recalculate a variable value every time it is used?

Tags: python

I want a variable to be calculated each time it is used.  For example, `var1 = var2 + var3` each time `var1` is printed.  How can I create a "dynamic" variable like this?

```
var2 = 4
var3 = 2
print(var1)  # 6
var3 = 8
print(var1)  # 12
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj No, it would not. That would check what is stored in var1, and then print what was the value of var1, it would not make any calculations.

Comment: Can you update your question with examples?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Whatever it would be necessary, for example, if I want var1 always be the sum of var2 and var3, every time I call var1, it would be necessary to sum var2 and var3 together and get a new value for var1

Comment: If you were in the context of an object, you'd be looking for [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), outside of objects, I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need a property on a class instance. The property will execute some code each time it's accessed. For example, here's a property that increments its value each time it is accessed. Define dunder methods that access the property to automatically increment it when performing operations on the object. For example, define `__str__` and `print(var)` will increment the value.

```
class MyVar(object):
    def __init__(self, initial=0):
        self._var1 = initial

    @property
    def var1(self):
        self._var1 += 1
        return self._var1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.var1)

var1 = MyVar()
print(var1)  # 1
print(var1)  # 2
print(var1.var1)  # 3
```

Calculate `var1 = var2 + var3`:

```
class MyVar(object):
    def __init__(self, var2, var3):
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3

    @property
    def var1(self):
        return self.var2 + self.var3

var = MyVar(4, 2)
print(var.var1)  # 6
var.var3 = 8
print(var.var1)  # 12
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also store the computation function in a variable and `call` it everytime you need the value:

```
>>> var1 = lambda: var2 + var3
>>> var2 = 4
>>> var3 = 2
>>> print(var1())
6
>>> var3 = 8
>>> print(var1())
12
```